# HTML on HTML lIke ReactJs JSX?

Tags: html

How to include the content on an html file, that is on the same folder, on the body of an other html file.

**index.html** | Ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta property="mymeta" content="Lot of meta" />
    <title>Some cool title</title>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    ! Include content.htm here !
</body>
</html>
```

**content.htm** | Ex:

```
<div></div>
<h1></h1>
<img src="https://404.com" />
...
```

Comment: An iframe is the closest thing that you can do in pure HTML. Otherwise, you'll have to go to server side parsing or client-side rendering with some ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `<embed>` tag. more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta property="mymeta" content="Lot of meta" />
    <title>Some cool title</title>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <embed type="text/html" src="content.html"  width="500" height="200">
</body>
</html>
```

or you can use `<iframe>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta property="mymeta" content="Lot of meta" />
    <title>Some cool title</title>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="content.html"  width="500" height="200">
</body>
</html>
```